# How do I make a numeric negative/positive range from -47 to 1123 in Regex?

Tags: regex

I want to make a numeric range with negative number to positiv number with using only 4 alternatives(|).

This is what I have done so far:

```
^[-+]?(?:-[0-9]|[0-9]|[0-7]?)$
```

I want the range to accept numbers between -47 to 1123.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not easy... but I guess this will do the trick.

`^(-4[0-7]|-[0-3]?[0-9])$|^(112[0-3]|11[01][0-9]|10[0-9]{2}|0?[0-9]{1,3})$`

see it live:
https://regex101.com/r/bFzBwZ/1

```js
const regex = /^(-4[0-7]|-[0-3]?[0-9])$|^(112[0-3]|11[01][0-9]|10[0-9]{2}|0?[0-9]{1,3})$/mg;
const str = `1123
1124
47
1122
0
11
-12
-78
-47
-33
-48
-11
-1
-3
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5
-14
-211
-471
-46`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: @DoppelEffect: It works, but you asked for 4 alternatives, here there are 6.

Comment: Yes I can live with it. Any suggestions on how to make it work with 4 alternatives @Toto?